# Adding files to folder in google drive

Tags: iphone, ios, google-drive-api

I have created the folder programmatically and it is appearing in google drive. Now I want to add files to the folder created. File is getting created but inside root folder. I don't want that to happen.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you `setParent` when you create the file info? It's a `ParentReference` added in the file info used in the `insert` requests. All you need to create the parent reference is the id of the parent (the folder you created) (and maybe a flag to note whether it's the root or not).